# Center image between buttons

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm trying to customise my blog on Tumblr, but I'm having some trouble. What I want is a picture centered horizontally in my blog, with a next and previous button around it. It should look like

> O [__] O

where the O's are my buttons and the [_] represents my picture.
How do I get the three elements together to be centered on my page and the buttons a certain amount of pixels away from the picture? Both buttons each have their own DIV, the photo has a class and there is one DIV enclosing the three of them.

My HTML is like this:

```
 <div class="photo-wrap">
<div id="previous">
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/gptupvc/hUhlxhrgd/next.png"></img>
</div>
                {block:Posts}


                {block:Photo}
<center>
<a href="{Permalink}"><img class="photo" src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"></img></a></center>
{/block:Photo}
{/block:Posts}
</div>
<div id="next">
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/gptupvc/hUhlxhrgd/next.png"></img>

</div>
```

with the following CSS

```
.photo-wrap {
        position:relative;
        margin-top:50px;
        width:1200px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-color:red;

    }

    .photo {
        float:left;
        height:600px;
        border-radius:10px;
        }

    #next {
        float:right;
        margin-top:-350px;
        background-color:green;

        }

    #next img {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }

    #previous {
        float:left;
        margin-top:250px;
        background-color:red;

        }

    #previous img {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a table!  Ha!  I know.  We aren't "allowed".  I don't have tumblr.  But I can answer this generally for any HTML.

Put your three widgets into a div and style it with style="text-align:center".  Now, anything you put inside of that div will be centered.

```
<div style="text-align:center">Stuff</div>
```

Next, put each of the widgets into their own divs and style them so that they appear "inline"

```
<div style="text-align:center">
   <div style="display:inline">Previous</div>
   <div style="display:inline">Button</div>
   <div style="display:inline">Next</div>
</div>
```

Last, you want spacing -- so fiddle with margin and padding until you get what you want.  For instance, try this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
   <div style="display:inline">Previous</div>
   <div style="display:inline;margin-left:25px;">Button</div>
   <div style="display:inline;margin-left:25px;">Next</div>
</div>
```

And you'll probably want to put all that styling in CSS ultimately.  But do that last.

By the way, another way to achieve horizontal spacing is to use "margin:0 auto" on the containing div.

Vertical centering is something all together different, but you didn't ask about that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try this code

```
 <style type="text/css">
 #image{float:left;}/*this is the important part to set float*/
 #male{float:left;}
 </style>

 <form>
 <input id="male" type="radio" name="sex" value="male" > Male
 <div id ="image"><img border="0" src="/images/pulpit.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304"      height="228" /></div>
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
 </form
```